# Unexpected token s in JSON at position 7 at parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: json, graphql

Why I get this error when I want to start the grahpql server?
I have no error on line 7
I want to start this server on port 3000 with json-graphql-server servergql.json.
[image: Error]

This is my data from servergql.json. But I have no error on line 7..why I get this error? Please help. Is a problem with node modules?

```
{
    students: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Pop Ion"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Pop Maria"
        }
        ],

    courses: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Web development",
            teacher: {
                id: 1,
                name: "Popescu Ion",
                office: 404
            }
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Java",
            teacher: {
                id: 1,
                name: "Ionescu Maria",
                office: 403
            }
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "Databases",
            teacher: {
                id: 1,
                name: "Marian Vasile",
                office: 401
            }
        }
        ],

    grades: [
        {
            course_id: 1,
            student_id: 1,
            grade: 7
        },
        {
            course_id: 1,
            student_id: 2,
            grade: 5
        },
        {
            course_id: 2,
            student_id: 1,
            grade: 5
        },
        {
            course_id: 2,
            student_id: 2,
            grade: 5
        },
        {
            course_id: 3,
            student_id: 2,
            grade: 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you've written is malformed - for a valid JSON file your object keys must be strings and must be contained within quotes ("").

The error you're seeing somewhat shows you what the problem is: `unexpected token s in JSON at position 7` which is highlighting that `students` is not expected in the object yet.

Valid JSON would be:

```json
{
    "students": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Pop Ion"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Pop Maria"
        }
        ],
    "courses": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Web development",
            "teacher": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Popescu Ion",
                "office": 404
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Java",
            "teacher": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Ionescu Maria",
                "office": 403
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Databases",
            "teacher": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Marian Vasile",
                "office": 401
            }
        }
        ],

    "grades": [
        {
            "course_id": 1,
            "student_id": 1,
            "grade": 7
        },
        {
            "course_id": 1,
            "student_id": 2,
            "grade": 5
        },
        {
            "course_id": 2,
            "student_id": 1,
            "grade": 5
        },
        {
            "course_id": 2,
            "student_id": 2,
            "grade": 5
        },
        {
            "course_id": 3,
            "student_id": 2,
            "grade": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

There are lots of online and development environment tools that you can use to lint your JSON to highlight any issues before you run into them in production (i.e. https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator)

Comment: Specifically, "position 7" does not mean line 7. It means the 7th character in the file, which here was an `s`.